# How to proxy pass when condition (related to param presence) is not met

Tags: nginx, proxypass

In Nginx I need to proxy pass some of the request made to the homepage.

Specificaly, I need to proxy pass them in case of URLs like:

```
example.com
example.com/
example.com/?anyTypeOfParameterButNotP
```

However, when the request contains `?p=` parameter in the URL, I would like to handle it the regular way (as if there wasn't any proxy_pass at all).

So, the URLs I would like not to proxy pass would be:

```
example.com/?p=1234
example.com/?p=1234&foo=bar
```

How can I achieve that?

I've tried some if statements, some variables solutions, but I didn't figure out any way to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something that can end with "break;"

```
location / {
    if ($query_string ~ p=) {
        ## regular way - try_file? and end with "break;"
    }
    proxy_pass http://somwhere;
}
```

--- or here is an if-else condition for unusual cases

```
location / {
    set $skip_proxy 0; 
    if ($query_string ~ p=) {
        set $skip_proxy 1;
    }

    if ($skip_proxy = 1) {
        # when query does contain ?p=
    }

    if ($skip_proxy = 0) {
        # when query does NOT contain ?p=
        # proxy_pass http://somwhere; ?
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.
The first solution gives me `Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is not allowed here` error, and the second one gives me `Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block` error.

Comment: please post your answer, and show your config file. i came across this issue in the morning. and came back only to find 1 of my own answers.